# Devissage lemma (Mumford's & Oda's AG II)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

This question is part II of my proof reading of [Lemma of devissage](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3372507/lemma-of-devissage-from-mumfords-agii)
from Mumford's & Oda's [Algebraic Geometry II](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Algebraic%20Geometry%20II%20%28a%20penultimate%20draft%29), findable on page 81; Theorem  6.12:

> Theorem 6.12 (“Lemma of devissage”). Let $K$ be the abelian category of coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules
>   on a noetherian scheme $X$, and K′ $\subset$ Ob(**K**) an exact subset. We have **K′** $=$ Ob(**K**),
>   if for any closed irreducible subset $Y ⊂ X$ with generic point $y$ there exists an coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$ module $\mathcal{G} ∈ $ **K′** with support
>   $Y$ such that  $\mathcal{G}_y$  is a one-dimensional $k(y)$-vector space.

few comments on *exact subset*: Let **K** be an abelian category, and denote by Ob(**K**) the set of its objects.
A subset **K′** $\subset$ Ob(**K**) is said to be exact if $0 ∈$ **K′** and if the following is satisfied: In an exact
sequence $0 → A′ → A → A′′ → 0$ in **K**, if two among $A, A′$ and $A′′$ belong to **K′**, then the third also
belongs to **K′**. we continue with the proof:

> **Proof**. For simplicity, a closed subset $Y ⊂ X$ is said to have property **P**($Y$) if any $\mathcal{S} ∈$
>   Ob(**K**) with $Supp(\mathcal{S}) ⊂ Y$ satisfies $\mathcal{S} ∈ $ **K′**.
>   We need to show that X has property **P**($X$).
>   By noetherian induction, it suffices to show that a closed subset $Y ⊂ X$ has property **P**($Y$)
>   if any closed subset $Y′ ⫋ Y$ has property **P**($Y'$).
>   Thus we now show $\mathcal{F} ∈ $ Ob(**K**) satisfies $\mathcal{F} ∈ $ **K′** if $Supp(\mathcal{F}) ⊂ Y$. Endow $Y$ with the unique
>   structure of closed reduced subscheme $Y_{red}$ of $X$ with the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ . Since $\mathcal{J} = \sqrt{\mathcal{J}} \subset \sqrt{Ann(\mathcal{F})}$, there
>   exists $n > 0$ such that $\mathcal{J}^n\mathcal{F} = (0)$. Looking at successive quotients in the filtration

$$ \mathcal{F} ⊃ \mathcal{J} \mathcal{F} ⊃ \mathcal{J}^2 \mathcal{F} ⊃ ... ⊃ \mathcal{J}^{n-1} \mathcal{F} ⊃ \mathcal{J}^n \mathcal{F} = (0) $$

> we may assume $n = 1$, that is, $\mathcal{J} \mathcal{F} = (0)$, in view of the exactness of **K′**. (???) Let $j : Y → X$ be the
>   closed immersion so that $\mathcal{F} = j_*j^*\mathcal{F}$.

Q: why the exactness of **K′** allows to reduce to the case that $n = 1$, i.e.  that $\mathcal{J} \mathcal{F} = (0)$? what is the argument which allows to perform this reduction?